# Kafka to Redis pub-sub sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, redis, apache-kafka-connect, publish-subscribe

We are looking for a Kafka sink connector that takes data from Kafka and publishes the data to a particular channel in Redis pub-sub. We came across the [Redis Sink Connector](https://www.confluent.io/hub/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-redis) but in docs they have mentioned about setting the data to Redis DB(Cache) instead of publishing the data to Redis pub-sub.
I checked their [git](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-redis) and found that there was an [issue](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-redis/issues/6) raised reg. this and a person named "Bradleywboggs" had written the code but it was not merged.
So my doubt is

1. Can the Redis Sink Connector be used for Kafka to Redis pub-sub data transfer ? (I personally feel **NO**)
2. If Redis Sink Connector cannot be used then is there any connector for Kafka to Redis pub-sub data transfer (or) Can I make changes(as done by Bradleywboggs) to the existing connector and use them?

[List of all kafka connectors](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/)

Comment: 2) Yes, you can checkout a fork and package it yourself

Comment: @OneCricketeer is it better to write custom connectors or create a micro-service which polls for the data using the consumer API(In our case this is easier since unlike connectors, consumers API can be written in JS - My team has expertise in JS).

Comment: Custom connectors can only be written in a JVM language, so that's up to you

Comment: @OneCricketeer in terms of performance, is connector(In AWS we can start an MSK Connect CLuster) better than micro-service(runs in EC2 instances) which polls for the data using the consumer API

Comment: Connect API is built over the consumer API, so no, but it offers a more unified configuration model

Answer (score 0):

If using **Redis PUB/SUB** is not a hard requirement and instead you would consider **Redis Streams** as a publish/subscribe message relay then it's supported here - https://www.confluent.io/hub/redis/redis-enterprise-kafka

Documentation - https://redis-field-engineering.github.io/redis-kafka-connect/#_sink_stream

FYI - Redis Streams comes with better delivery guarantee semantics than Redis PUB/SUB since the messages are durable and allow for consumer groups, similar to kafka.